# Modify Loop to include 3 strings

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code I use to go through a sheet and parse the information onto separate sheets based on the string [Start].

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long, rFind As Range, rFind1 As Range, rFind2 As Range, rFind3 As Range, rFind4 As Range, ws As Worksheet, s As String, s1 As String, s2 As String

    s = "[Start]"

    With Sheets("Full History File").Columns(1)
        
        Set rFind3 = .Find(What:="[HistoryEnd]", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set rFind = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1)
        
        For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*" & s & "*")
        
        Set rFind = .Find(What:=s, After:=rFind, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
            If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            
                Set rFind1 = .Find(What:=s, After:=rFind)
                Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                ws.Name = "Blasted " & i
            
                If i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*" & s & "*") Then
                
                    Set rFind1 = rFind2.Offset(1)
            
                End If
            
                Range(rFind, rFind1.Offset(-1)).Copy ws.Range("A1")
        
            End If
    
        Next i

    End With

    Sheets("Blast Summary Sheet").Select

    SheetNames

    CommandButton6.Visible = True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

My problem is that the information I am working through has changed and I need to adapt the code to do the following:

1. Search for the string [TrainingModeChanged]
2. If not found search for the string [TrainingMode]
3. If not found search for the string [Start]

Once any of the strings are found create the new sheet Blasted with the number and copy the information between the found string up until the next found string which could be either one of the 3 above.

All help in modify the code to do this would be helpfull thanks

Comment: You need to come up with a precise question. Where exactly did you get stuck or erros? Just asking how to adapt your code is too broad. Please try something on your own first, then tell what went wrong in your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are after, but you could write a function that returns your required string instead of hardcoding it. Function below:

```vb
Option Explicit

Function getString() As String
    
    'we will use On Error Resume Next to by pass the expected error if cannot find the string
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim searchRng As Range
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    
    
    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Full History File")
    
    'search for first range
    Set searchRng = mySheet.Columns(1).Find(What:="[TrainingModeChanged]", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not searchRng Is Nothing Then
        'this means search range was found
        getString = searchRng.Value
        'reset error handling
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'implicit to say if program runs here first search was unsuccessful
    Set searchRng = mySheet.Columns(1).Find(What:="[TrainingMode]", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not searchRng Is Nothing Then
        'this means search range was found
        getString = searchRng.Value
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    'implicit to say if program runs here second search was unsuccessful
    Set searchRng = mySheet.Columns(1).Find(What:="[Start]", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not searchRng Is Nothing Then
        'this means search range was found
        getString = searchRng.Value
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Function
    End If
    
End Function
```

And you call in your routine as:

```vb
s = getString()
```

And then continue on with your code..